# Mac OS Nativescript Sidekick UI flickering

Tags: macos, nativescript, vmware-workstation

My host OS is Windows 10 and I have installed Mac OS Mojave on it it with using Vmware. My pc's GPU is Intel HD 4600. It is on board. Screen resolution is 1366 x 768px and it is LCD. I have mounted darwin.iso for installing wmvare tools. Mac OS is working good. But nativescript sidekicks UI is flickering as loop. Other app UI have not any problem. I have tried it on High Sierra too but result is same

**EDIT**

You can make a script this command `open -a NativeScript\ Sidekick --args --disable-gpu` as with [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277042/how-to-create-a-universal-script-file-for-a-mac-based-on-several-terminal-com/277044#277044?newreg=6a109613a4e64d97a51f36396eba05c4) instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to run Sidekick in a Terminal by using this command.

**open -a NativeScript\ Sidekick --args --disable-gpu**